# Database connection is showing

Tags: database, connection

When I try to connect my database with "dbconnect.php", it is showing like this:

> could not connect: Access denied for user 'zigmasta_ajas'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

Why does this happen? I don't know much about sql and php. My website is hosted. The host provides *phpmyadmin* and mysql database.I have created a database and a user using mysql wizard. I think all are going well. Then why does this error happen? Please help me in detail.

The following is php code I used. please check the code. Does this code contain errors?

```
    <?php
      $user_name="zigmasta_ajas";
       $password="password";
       $server="127.0.0.1";
       $database="zigmasta_dbtest";
       $db_handle=mysql_connect($server,$user_name,
       $password);
       if(!$db_handle)
         {
       die('could not connect:'.mysql_error());
       }
        echo'connected successfully';
         $db_found=mysql_select_db($database);
         if($db_found)
            {
          echo"database found";
            }
        else{
          echo"database not found";
                }
           mysql_close($db_handle);
         ?>
```

Comment: Does the username and password work when you connect to the db with other tools?

Comment: Which other tools?

Comment: Anything that can connect to the database. Whatever you built the table with, a commandline sql tool, anything really.

Comment: I have some php files to access table elements from database.but those files require "dbconnect.php".The connection by dbconnect.php is showing as error